# Why does deadlifts makes you feel like you are going to pass out? Can it be avoided?

Tags: health, deadlifts, tiredness

More than any of the other exercises that I do, whenever I complete a set (10 reps) of deadlifts (appx 175 pounds not as much as I see other people do), I feel the need to hold on to something or sit down.  Why is that?  I've even seen videos of people passing out after doing deadlifts.

Can this be avoided / effect minimised?

Comment: Valsalva - basically like trying to exhale against closed airways. Always breathe when lifting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing the [Valsalva maneuver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valsalva_maneuver) during deadlifts, then it is possible to get light headed during. Overcoming it will come with experience. Though, it's common for people to hold their breath **during the entire set** which is **not** what you want to do. This is especially true for those that "bounce" the bar (disengage and immediately pull).

To make sure you have enough oxygen throughout the set:

1. Perform a few really deep breaths before grabbing the bar.
2. Grab the bar
3. Deep breath in to the stomach and hold
4. Pull the lift
5. Disengage
6. Exhale

Repeat 3 - 6 until set is complete.

Do not rush the set. Do not bounce. It's not a race. Take as many breaths between reps as you need. Reset each rep if you have to.